# ¿Debo excluir .slconfig del control de versiones?

Tags: control-de-versiones

Estoy usando SonarLint en mi proyecto de .NET Core. Cuando integro los proyectos con SonarLint se generan los siguientes archivos dentro de la carpeta `.sonarlint`:

- `<NombreProyectoSonarQube>CSharp.ruleset`
- `<NombreSolucion>.slconfig`

El archivo `.ruleset` contiene las reglas para Sonarlint and SonarQube así que mantengo este archivo en el control de versiones.

Pero que hay acerca del `.slconfig` ¿Debo mantener este archivo en el control de versiones o debo excluirlo? (agregarlo a `.gitignore` en mi caso)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este archivo **Sí** debe incluirse en el control de versiones.

Este archivo controla la sincronización del código fuente y SonarQube.

Incluye entre otras cosas:

- `ServerUri` que apunta al servidor de SonarQube al cual está enlazado el proyecto.
- `ProjectKey` con el key del proyecto en el servidor SonarQube.
- `Profiles` que incluye `ProfileKey` que es un identificador para el *Quality profile* seleccionado en el servuidor.

Fuente: Esta publicación del SonarSource community: [SonarLint source control](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarlint-source-control/2892/2)